# Transform imperative algorithm into formula (or prove they produce the same output)

Tags: swift, algorithm

I saw someone write the code below:

```
var row = 0
var incr = true 
var numRows = 5
for idx in 0..<10 {
    print(row)
    if row == 0 {
        incr = true
    } else if row == numRows - 1 {
        incr = false 
    }
    row = (incr) ? row+1 : row-1
}
```

The code's goal is to make the variable "row" increase and decrease like:

```
row = 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 2 1 ...
```

But the author improves his code and the result likes below

```
var numRows = 5
let L = numRows - 1
for idx in 0..<10 {
    row = L - abs(L - idx % (2*L))
}
```

I know the result of "row" is the same, but I don't know how to transfer version 1 to version 2. How do I prove that it's the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Prove" it but if you write out the path of each variable and the numbers at each interval, you're basically showing that the two outputs are the same (if they are, I haven't checked).

Comment: `%` is the remainder operator (sometimes called the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)), and `abs` returns the absolute value of a number. The rest is just math.

Comment: I know what is % or abs meaning , i just don't know how to transfer the first one to second one,Can you understand i mean?

Comment: So start with `idx=0` and do the math with a pencil and paper. Then do `idx=1`. By the time you get to 10, you should understand it pretty well.

Comment: I can write the first one by myself,but i cant figure out the second one,so i need to know why the author can figure out that formula and how to rewrite

Comment: btw the result of them are not the same

Comment: It's the same. How are not the same?

Comment: the first one starts at 1 the second starts at 0

Comment: All start at 0, i don't know why you think first one starts at 1?

Comment: Just look at print result not the variable value

Comment: In my testing they produce the same sequence.

Comment: @robmayoff  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]` and `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]` are similar but not the same

Comment: All print result are  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]

Comment: I completely agree. Those are different sequences. However, when I copy and paste the first program into a playground, I don't get output that starts with 1. I get output that starts with 0. And when I copy and paste the second program into a playground (and change the `row = ...` to `print(...)`), I get the same sequence, also starting with 0.

Comment: @LeoDabus Furthermore, it is trivial to see by inspection that the first program starts by printing zero, because it initializes `var row = 0` and the first `print` statement prints `row` and it does not assign to `row` between the initialization and the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing a formula like that requires an understanding of and familiarity with the modulo and absolute values operators. These are things that you develop over time if you play with math problems and read programs. Once you get the hang of them, you can figure out other formulas that give the same result, such as `abs((i + L) % (2 * L) - L)`.

Anyway, given the formula in your question, try to convince yourself that it does what the first program does by building up the formula one step at a time and graphing the steps.

Computing `i % (2*L)` for 0 ≤ i < ∞ gives a repeating cycle of the integers from 0 to 2*L (including 0 but excluding 2*L):

[image: i % (2*L)]

Computing `L - i % (2*L)` turns that into a repeating cycle of the integers from L down to -L (including L but excluding -L):

[image: L - i % (2*L)]

Taking the absolute value of that sequence (`abs(L - i % (2*L))`) changes the negative part of the sequence to positive, so you get a repeating cycle of first the integers from L down to 0, then back up to L (including the first L and 0 but not the second L, so you don't get two L's in a row):

[image: abs(L - i % (2*L))]

Subtracting that sequence from L (`L - abs(L - i % (2*L))`) flips L to 0, L-1 to 1, etc., and 0 to L. So you get a repeating cycle from 0 to L and back to 0 (including 0 and L but not repeating 0 twice in a row):

[image: L - abs(L - i % (2*L))]

This is the same sequence produced by the first program.

Comment: Thank that is an answer i want, btw how to draw that pic ? Is that a tool?

Comment: I think he got it from Xcode's playgrounds feature

Comment: Actually I used Mathematica. For the final graph: `Export["/Users/mayoff/Desktop/plot5.png", 
 DiscretePlot[L - Abs[L - Mod[i, 2 L]], {i, 0, 40}]]`